# How to detect if ctrl + enter in an Excel spreadsheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My understanding is: Macro canNOT be activated while a cell is active for editing.

I notice by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, the cell is de-activate for editing but remain selected. I would like then to run some macro refer to this cell.

Therefore, using VBA, how to detect if <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the timely replies, however, I still need a mechanism to detect if "ctrl+ enter" has been pressed. Because I have used worksheet_change for other functions and I want to trigger some special only if "ctrl+ enter" is pressed. I have tried using Application.Onkey, it seems only assign my function to the key combination, but not conducting a condition test. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way should be using the `Change` event of the worksheet.
This would not (only) detect a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> but any change of a cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

This sub has to be added to the worksheets code (not into a module)!

---

Another approach would be using the `OnKey` Method

```
 Application.OnKey "^{RETURN}", "InsertProc"
```

See here for a decent explanation: [Application.OnKey Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx)

Comment: You might say: Not only would this detect a Ctrl+Enter, but also any change of cell. Because it kind of reads like you're saying it won't detect the Ctrl+Enter when in fact it does!

Comment: @RobinMackenzie OK, I improved my wording a bit. But it really doesn't detect the Ctrl+Enter directly it detects the end of the edit mode regardless if the cell content changed or not.

Comment: agreed - it doesn't specifically catch Ctrl+Enter - just has that effect because the cell changed. just makes your answer read better!